# Which Oracle Analytic Function should I use to get this result?

Tags: sql, oracle, ranking, row-number

Probably a dummy question, but it is Sunday and my mind does not work as it should be. I am trying to use an analytic function to get the following

I have this query ( it is just a small example of one record but enough for what I am trying to explain )

```
   select h.party_number,organization_name,address_line1,address_type 
      ,row_number() over(partition by party_number,organization_name,address_line1 order by address_line1,address_type ) as newrn
from h 
where party_number = 'FI-110584'
order by address_type,party_number;
```

Which gives me this result

[image]

What I really want is to have the same ranking ( so the same number ) for the combination of party_number, organization_name and adress_line1

So, the last column should look like

1

1

2

Because the same party_number, organization_name and address_line should be given the same ranking value.

What analytic function should I use here ? I tried `dense_rank` and `rank` with no success.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partitioning and ordering is a little off:

```
select h.party_number,organization_name,address_line1,address_type 
      ,dense_rank() over(partition by party_number,organization_name order by address_line1 ) as newrn
from h 
where party_number = 'FI-110584'
order by address_type,party_number;
```

| PARTY_NUMBER | ORGANIZATION_NAME | ADDRESS_LINE1 | ADDRESS_TYPE | NEWRN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FI-110584 | NEKAPAINO OY | GOLFKENTÄNTIE 4 | Default | 1 |
| FI-110584 | NEKAPAINO OY | GOLFKENTÄNTIE 4 | DivAdd | 1 |
| FI-110584 | NEKAPAINO OY | PL 100 | InvAdd | 2 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bd96ce35ba64e61e26bca3be70c5dfec)

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like it is `DENSE_RANK` **without** `ADDR` column you're looking for:

```
SQL> with test (party, org, addr) as
  2    (select 'fi-11', 'neka', 'golfe 4' from dual union all
  3     select 'fi-11', 'neka', 'golfe 4' from dual union all
  4     select 'fi-11', 'neka', 'pl 100'  from dual
  5    )
  6  select t.*,
  7    dense_rank() over (partition by party, org order by addr) rnk
  8  from test t
  9  order by addr;

PARTY ORG  ADDR           RNK
----- ---- ------- ----------
fi-11 neka golfe 4          1
fi-11 neka golfe 4          1
fi-11 neka pl 100           2

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer as well. I was so tired yesterday after two weeks without rest that the obvious answer was eluding me. I'm even a little bit embarrassed for asking the question, but my brain was in holidays yesterday ;)

Comment: No problem, happens to me too (probably more often than I'd like to :)).

Answer (score 0):

You need a DENSE_RANK not ROW_NUMBER -

```
SELECT h.party_number,
       organization_name,
       address_line1,
       address_type,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY party_number,organization_name,address_line1 ORDER BY address_type) as newrn
  FROM h 
 WHERE party_number = 'FI-110584'
 ORDER BY address_type, party_number;
```